# Code structure / pattern for Hooks & Context & (State / Reducer)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

- How could I refactor my code below to have a better, cleaner code,
  and respect the best practices as I feel the current code is really
  messy.
- With the code below, should I switch from useState to useReducer?
  Should the reducer be in a separate file (e.g.:
  src/reducers/NotificationReducer.js)?
- Also, where should I implement the function to fetch the data? In the
  component / context / something else? I feel like fetching the data in the context is wrong and doesnt belong here.

src/context/NotificationsContext.js   - (simplified)

```
export const NotificationsContext = createContext()

export const NotificationsProvider = (props) => {
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(null)
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext)
  const [hasNewNotifications, setHasNewNotifications] = useState(false)
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  async function fetchData() {
    setIsLoading(true)
    ...
    // fetching the data
    ..
    setHasNewNotifications(...)
    setNotifications(...)
    setTotalPages(...)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  async function readNotification() {
    // sending the request to read the notification
    setNotifications(...)
  }


  return (
    <NotificationsContext.Provider
      value={[
        notifications,
        setNotifications,
        isLoading,
        setIsLoading,
        hasNewNotifications,
        setHasNewNotifications,
        fetchData,
        readNotification,
      ]}
    >
      {props.children}
    </NotificationsContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

src/components/Notifications.js   - (simplified)

```
const Notification = ({index}) => {
  const [
    notifications,
    setNotifications,
    loading,
    setIsLoading,
    hasNewNotifications,
    setHasNewNotifications,
    fetchData,
    readNotification,
  ] = useContext(NotificationsContext)


  return (
    <div>
        notifications.map((notif, index) => {
            return <Notification index={index}/> //the component Notification holds the actual representation for a notification
        })
    </div>
  )
}

export default Notification
```

src/components/Notification.js   - (simplified)

```
const Notification = ({index}) => {
  const [
    notifications,
    setNotifications,
    loading,
    setIsLoading,
    hasNewNotifications,
    setHasNewNotifications,
    fetchData,
    readNotification,
  ] = useContext(NotificationsContext)


  return (
    // very simplified compenent to understand better
    <div></div>
        <button onClick={() => readNotification(...)}
        <div>{notifications[index].message</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Notification
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already looking at quite a few things to happen in your component. There is just not much you can do unless you switch to state management outside your component.
Have a look at [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/quick-start) it will show you how to structure your app in features e.g.: users, notifications and authedUser for instance. Also fetchData would become an [async thunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk) while “hasNewNotifications” and “isLoading” can be set depending on your async request status (pending/fulfilled/rejected)